displaying characters using iced/rust
I'm following the "first steps" guide on iced's website
for some reason characters don't render properly, so instead of + - or the number in the counter, i just get squares. the counter seems to work otherwise, if i click the plus button 10 times the number is rendered as 2 squares(one square for each digit). I'm building on ubuntu 23.04 if that matters. here's a screenshot of my cool counter:

How do i display symbols and numbers other than 'square' using iced?

figured it out!
So this issue was apparently a font issue.
I have no idea if this is the best solution to the issue, but i managed to get it working by setting the default font of my application, like so:
fn main() -> iced::Result {
    iced::application(
        "A cool counter",
        Counter::update,
        Counter::view,
    )
        .default_font(iced::Font::MONOSPACE)
        .run()
}

I noticed that iced has a font called iced::Font::DEFAULT, I'm guessing that font refers to some system font that doesn't exist on my machine for whatever reason, but again, that's just a guess. Explicitly setting MONOSPACE as the font worked for me, if someone else has a similar issue and MONOSPACE doesn't exist either, I guess you might have to load a custom font or something.
